# Interpolation in a keras lambda layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How can I 1d interpolate in a keras lambda layer?

The output of my lambda layer needs to be interpolated at the right query points in order to match the y inputs of my neural network.

I tried to use np.interp but the gradients are not propagated when calling numpy functions

Comment: There is no gradient (loss) compute inside the Lambda layer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A partial answer to your question should be doing 1D interpolation in **tensorflow** with [tfp.math.interp_regular_1d_grid](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/interp_regular_1d_grid) as mentioned in the documentation. Further, It needs to be checked how to use its output in Keras Lambda layer